# Change scroll direction at Anchor point

Tags: javascript, jquery

on my site I have 6 divs each div the same height and width of the browser window, so 5 are out of view, 3 left aligned then 3 more on top, as so....

[image]

When my visitors scroll, id like to scroll along to the 3rd div, then scroll up to the 4th, then continue scrolling horizontally. Is this possible with jQuery, and if so how can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. It allows you to scroll in different directions and set up "slides" like above

http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Answer (score 1):

Simple (maybe helpful) and not perfect:

```
var win = $(window),
    doc = $(document),
    bodyH = doc.height() - win.height(),
    page4 = $('#page4');

win.scrollTop(bodyH);


$(document).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e, delta) {
    delta = delta || -e.originalEvent.detail / 3 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120;

    if(delta < 0) {
        if(win.scrollLeft() > page4.offset().left && win.scrollTop() !== 0) {
            win.scrollTop(win.scrollTop() + delta * 30);
        } else {
            win.scrollLeft(win.scrollLeft() - delta * 30);
        }
    } else {
        if(win.scrollLeft() < page4.offset().left && (win.scrollTop() > 0 || win.scrollTop() === 0) && win.scrollTop() !== bodyH) {
            win.scrollTop(win.scrollTop() + delta * 30);
        } else {
            win.scrollLeft(win.scrollLeft() - delta * 30);
        }
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/EaUeF/)**