# Stop Javascript/change scroll direction at anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I've got a site that is using the [jInvertScroll](http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/) plugin to do horizontal scrolling. The issue is, I want the last two blocks of my website to remain vertically oriented and scrolled.

I'm looking for a way to only do the invertscroll on the first two sections. I'm thinking by either only running the script when between two anchor points, or somehow overriding the script. Open to any suggestions though.

I have looked at this question: [Change scroll direction at Anchor point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726887/change-scroll-direction-at-anchor-point)
but the path plugin is a lot above what I need, and I'd love to not have to completely change how I'm scrolling again, as I'm dealing with many stacked elements and a canvas.

My site's bones are essentially this:

```
<div id="scrollbox">
  <header class="block" id="block1">
  </header>
  <section class="block" id="block2">
  </section>
  <section class="block" id="block3">
  </section>
  <section class="block" id="block4"> 
  </section>
</div>
```

with this css:

```
#scrollbox {
  display: flex;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width: 2000px;
}
.block {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
#block1 {
  background-color:red;
}
#block2 {
  background-color:black;
}
#block3 {
  background-color:green;
}
#block4 {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle with what I have. What I'm trying to do is place the yellow block under the green block, and have scrolling return to normal to scroll down from the green to the yellow (vertically).
https://jsfiddle.net/acoustic7/qnr7L86g/1/

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for `flex-direction: column-reverse`, but I can't tell exactly what you mean by "*have downward scrolling switch to down*". Your fiddle is also broken, which I believe would demonstrate what you mean -- can you please correct the fiddle / clarify?

Comment: @ObsidianAge thank you for pointing out that the fiddle was broken, it's been updated. You're right also that I was unclear on that last sentence. What I want is for scrolling to return to normal to scroll down to the yellow block from the green block.